# SQL: How to use WHERE instead of OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, join, where-clause, sqlbase

I am using an old database call Centura Gupta that doesn't have the `join` clauses (left join, right join, inner join, outer join). So I need to use `where` to replace the `outer join` that I need:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.id_person table2.id_person;
```

I think that `where` can only replaces `inner join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.id_person = table2.id_person;
```

Comment: (1) There is no such thing as `OUTER JOIN`.  (2) Tag with the database you are really using.  I know of no database that doesn't support `JOIN` and hasn't for the past 15 years (so I'm curious).  (3) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Do you need `FULL JOIN` ? or only left/right join? BTW: table2 is missing in your second query.

Comment: Based on my searches, I'm wondering if this is OpenText SQLBase. This syntax guide looks helpful. There is a section on joins, including "outer joins": http://apachepersonal.miun.se/~parfor/databaser00/lang.pdf

Comment: Comma is cross join (with lower precedence than keyword joins) & inner join on is cross join where. Expressing left & other outer joins by join is a faq. Expressing join on with cross join & where is a faq.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use subqueries instead of join

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE id_Person IN 
(
SELECT id_Person
FROM table2 
)
```

Comment: This is not the equivalent of a JOIN.

Comment: ok, please provide column names that you needed, with the table name. I'll update subquery

Answer (score 0):

I used this kind of implementation when I didn't know JOINs. May not be exactly right but something  which can get you close:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.id_Person=t2.id_Person;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that particular database, but you might be able to use a correlated subquery to get "joined" data. This will pull all records from `table1` and the related info from `table2`, or NULL for `whatever4` and `whatever5` if there's no matching `id_person` in `table2`:

```
SELECT t1.whatever1
    , t1.whatever2
    , t1.whatever3
    , (SELECT whatever4 FROM table2 AS t2 WHERE t2.id_person = t1.id_person) AS whatever4
    , (SELECT whatever5 FROM table2 AS t2 WHERE t2.id_person = t1.id_person) AS whatever5
FROM table1 AS t1
```

Answer (score 0):

**'Old database called Centura Gupta'** ??
Maybe you actually mean **OpenText Gupta SQLBase** - which is by no means 'old'.
You may be running an 'old' version of SQLBase - but it is now up to v12.2 native 64bit, and outer joins are certainly supported.
You can either use the native Gupta outer joins - similar to Oracle (+) or standard ANSI outer joins.
If you want to use ANSI OUTER joins, specify 'ANSIJoinSyntax=1' in your Server side Sql.ini

Go here for more SQLBase Join syntax: [Gupta SQLBase Manuals](https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/SqlBase_Books/)

Native Gupta Outer Join:

> SELECT t1.id_person, t2.id_person
> From table1 t1 , table t2
> Where t1.id_person = t2.id_person(+)

ANSI Outer Join:

```
SELECT t1.person_id, t2.person_id   
From table1 t1
Left Outer Join table2 t2 ON t1.id_person = t2.id_person
Where <what ever filter you want>
```

Go here for more SQLBase Join syntax: [Gupta SQLBase Manuals](https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/SqlBase_Books/)